# Correcting a NullReferenceException in PositionWithLocationProvider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mapbox, foursquare, arkit

I am working through the [How to build an Augmented Reality App using the Foursquare API + Mapbox + ARKit](https://medium.com/foursquare-developers/how-to-build-an-augmented-reality-app-using-the-foursquare-api-mapbox-arkit-b8873f110e85) sample project and receive the following error at runtime:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Mapbox.Examples.LocationProvider.PositionWithLocationProvider.get_LocationProvider () (at Assets/PositionWithLocationProvider.cs:42)
Mapbox.Examples.LocationProvider.PositionWithLocationProvider.Start () (at Assets/PositionWithLocationProvider.cs:63)
```

Taking a look at `PositionWithLocationProvider.cs`, this is the block in question:

```cs
ILocationProvider _locationProvider;
public ILocationProvider LocationProvider
{
  private get
  {
    if (_locationProvider == null)
    {
      _locationProvider = _useTransformLocationProvider ?
      LocationProviderFactory.Instance.TransformLocationProvider : LocationProviderFactory.Instance.DefaultLocationProvider; // Line 42
    }

    return _locationProvider;
  }
  set
  {
    if (_locationProvider != null)
    {
      _locationProvider.OnLocationUpdated -= LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated;

    }
    _locationProvider = value;
    _locationProvider.OnLocationUpdated += LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated;
  }
}
Vector3 _targetPosition;

void Start()
{
  LocationProvider.OnLocationUpdated += LocationProvider_OnLocationUpdated; // Line 63
  _map.OnInitialized += () => _isInitialized = true;
}
```

(The full file can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/garethpaul/5b3505ecc72314931b7c1d1df8f5f712).)

I know that `_locationProvider` is null at this point but I'm not sure why my `LocationProviderFactory.Instance` would be bombing out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you know that the problem is `LocationProviderFactory.Instance` ?

Comment: @Programmer I'm not certain—it was an assumption based on exception.

Comment: Double-click on that error from the Editor and it should take you to where the problem is in your code. Post which line of code it is.

Comment: Do you have assigned LocationProviders on your LocationProviderFactory object? [Example of null providers...](https://ibb.co/cVPeRG)

Comment: @Programmer Suffering from the MonoDevelop auto-crash on High Sierra at the moment—I may try out their patch later today so I can at least get more info.

Comment: Just use Visual Studio. Can't believe people still use MonoDevelop in 2017.

Comment: @mayo Thanks for the suggestion—I don't currently have a LocationProviderFactory object... it doesn't appear there were instructions for it in that demo project. Eep—this appears to be the route I need to research.

Comment: Sorry to offend, @Programmer: this is my first foray into Unity and I'm just trying to find stable ground before expanding out to new tools.